# Symfony 4, how print logs in profiler log page?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

From php files in Symfony 4, how can I print variables (for debug) to the log profiler page ?

I mean this page :

[image]

I tried that :

```
$log = new Logger()
$log->info("test");

$log2 = new ConsoleLogger(OutputInterface::OUTPUT_NORMAL);
$log2->alert("hello !");
```

But nothing appears...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just follow the monolog symfony guide : http://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html

After logger install, I add somewhere in a controller a "$logger->info("foo");" and I see the trace from the log profiler page

Answer (score 3):

You may not have installed the monolog bundle. Without that you get a very rudimentary logging.

Run:

```
composer require symfony/monolog-bundle
```

Reload app and see if message start appearing in the log tab of the profiler.